# Trouble connecting to PostgreSQL container through pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, pgadmin

I am currently working on a school project and I need to connect to a PostgreSQL container through pgAdmin. I have used docker-compose to create the container instance of PostgreSQL and PostGIS.

But when I try to connect to my PostgreSQL container, it does not work. Maybe I have entered the details wrongly? I have attached a screenshot here of the docker-compose.yml file and the parameters that I have filled in on my pgAdmin Desktop.

What am I doing wrong?[image: picture of what I did]

[netstat-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgg5i.jpg)

Can anyone please help me? Would really appreciate it !!

Answer (score 0):

Your db container's outside port is `54320`, not `5432`. You are trying to connect `postgis` container instead of `postgres`. And your passwords are different from each other.

You can do one of the below;

- If you still want to connect to `postgis`, you can use password accordingly.
- If you want to connect to `postgres`, change port to `54320` in `pgAdmin`.

Comment: Hey Aygun - thanks for replying ! 

I have tried changing to port 54320 to connect to postgres, but it still does not work :( Do you have any other tips?

Comment: can you share your `netstat -nltp` output? Are ports open? Also can you try to connect with the second password you wrote below?